# Ability system in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

I'm new to Unity, but not programming in general. I have a turn based RPG type game and I'm wondering if anyone has comments/thoughts/ideas on the below structure that I'm thinking about for this system. The main idea is that in a file I save what actors/characters have what abilities by name. The abilities have a Do() function that does the actual ability sequence (since it's turn based the abilities are sequential in nature. jump here, do this, jump back, or spin, then move here, then here, then here, then back in the case of a whirlwind ability). Is adding the ability as a component the right thing to do? The abilities work on the game object and it seems deriving them from MonoBehavior gives you a lot of functionality to work on the game object so it seemed like the right thing to do, but I'm not 100% sure.

```
class Actor : Monobehavior{
    private List<Ability> abilities;
    public string name;

    void Start(){
        // read json file to populate the abilities this actor has based on it's name
        // but until then the basic idea is below
        var strike = gameobject.AddComponent<MeleeStrike>() as Ability;
        strike.Owner = this;

        abilities.Add(strike);
    }
}   

interface IAbility{
    IEnumerable Do(Actor target);
}

class Ability : Monobehavior, IAbility{
    Actor owner;
}

class MeleeStrike : Ability{
    // this function will be called as a coroutine so we can do the sequence
    // that is this ability
    public IEnumerable Do(Actor target){
        // jump in front of our target
        Helper.JumpToPosition(target);

        // wait .5 seconds

        // play strike animation which will have event on hit to play sounds/effects/etc

        // wait .5 seconds

        // jump back to our position
        Helper.JumpToPosition(owner);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just like any other software, if it meets your requirements and it's maintainable, you're good to go! We can't decide those things for you however. If you'd still like to discuss the code, you should ask on something like a forum gamedev.net or reddit.com/r/gamedev

Comment: I don't know if it'll be maintainable though. I'm new to Unity and someone who has more experience in Unity would be able to tell me the pitfalls of my approach given Unity's unique way of doing things. That's what I'm after really. I'm sure someone has done something similar in Unity and found tips and tricks for such things.

Comment: I came into Unity as a software developer already too. You can do most things just like you would in regular software, it's just object oriented programming. You don't have to do it in a "Unity way".

Comment: If you have interface, why do you use `Ability` type for the list? The more components you have on a gameObject, the longer is an execution of `GetComponent<>()`. As well, you use more memory, as for every component there are a lot of pointers stored to items like `transform`, `gameObject`, `tag`, `useGUILayout`,  ... and also many deprecated pointers. Thus, even though, component based system is pretty good to maintain to some point to around 3-5 max components on 1 game object, I prefer to choose standart objects if it's possible and it's a better choice.

Comment: The logic of Ability with physics and it's visuals can be split up. Visuals can be stored in scriptable objects that corresponding abilities have access via public in another object or static variables. Though, it's better for not components part to not take a responsibility of controlling object, Ability can work as an interface of calling the actual ability - instantiating it, passing it the target and any values needed. With that you will have saved memory as well as flyweight pattern. Don't forget about object pool. Don't use string hashing for object pool, you have `GetInstanceID()`.

Comment: If it's a game like MMO games where you have about 120+ abilities, you can go even further and make all the abilities in to be stored in some interface and to act like interfaces themselves, though, you will still need to have data about your character ability like dmg, power.... as every other character can have different set of stats. Or you could use some formulas to calculate abilities damage depending on level (still needs some `AbilityData`) of the ability and stats. But that is extreme case where you would be trying to micro optimize. If it's for mobile MMO 120+ ab. RAM would be happy.

Comment: If you have low amount of abilities per character don't worry about splitting them up. Also the case above works the same for RTS, TBS .... games that have a lot of units. You can't have every other ability to be stored in 1000+ units on the screen. You can till you hit the problem. But it's better to optimize at the end if you don't have intentions of re-using this code. If you will reuse it, then it's a good choice to make it with good quality, so that next time you have ready interfaces and abstractions for ability system that is easy to use and is light on memory.

Comment: @MichaelHouse even though it may seem like opinion-based, I would say that this question just requires an answer that will cover many cases. In the end it always comes to reduce memory, processor and video card usage. But his question was even in different aspect. You can see that OP has doubts about MonoBehaviour, he doesn't know if it has any pitfalls or not in using it. The one thing that stackexchange lacks is a combination of questions that have answers on common questions that every newcomer wants to know. It's true that he can figure out it's own system for everything in a game.

Comment: @MichaelHouse But without knowledge of Computer System Architecture and Operational Systems, patterns and game programming patters - it's hard to figure out by yourself. People can say that it's opinion based but every opinion based answer has background to why someone answered this way, thus it has some positive impact on solution. Then there is the best solution for every genre of game or for the whole game as a bigger pattern. Then it's no longer opinion-based as it can be answered for the particular game genre.